# How do I read proc/stat from android device?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a cpu usage monitoring application and I was wondering how I can read proc/stat from Android application.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

Just read it like any other file...

```
try {
    BufferedReader mounts = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/stat"));
    String line;

    while ((line = mounts.readLine()) != null) {
        // do some processing here
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Cannot find /proc/stat...");
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Ran into problems reading /proc/stat...");
}
```

Comment: Does the phone need to be rooted or anything to have the permissions to read that file?